# Develop Visual Basic Excel DLL Addins - Project Description / Start Program

Tags: vb6, ide

I would like to develop a Visual Basic 6 IDE Addin that can move complied DLL to a temporary folder.
The purpose will let Excel application call the correct DLL during VB6 IDE debugging environment.

I been study the VBP files of VB6 draw out, and found 2 attributes("Description" and "DebugStartupComponent") and in VBP file will be changed.
"Description" Attribute will show out in Excel Reference dialog
"DebugStartupComponent" Attribute will effect VB6 IDE call Excel and also Excel opened target file.

Actually, I have written the project as a temporary stage, but may occur some bugs as below listed.

1. After change "DebugStartupComponent" attribute from "EHVB6AddinDebugCmdLineForm".
   **VB6 IDE needs to save "Group1.vbg"?**
2. After change "DebugStartupComponent" attribute from "EHVB6AddinDebugCmdLineForm".
   **VB6 IDE may crash?!**

Anyone have any ideas of this? it maybe I can change "Start Program" not from VBP File, or from VB6 VBInstance.VBProjects attribute, or something like that.
please find enclosed ZIP file as the developed Addin project.
[VB6 Addin Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-vgcI1lHu5bfv1rXpnB-kAHT4Oa2KZop/view?usp=sharing)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Programs loading VB6 DLLs do not load them based on their file location. They are loaded based on a registry lookup. It is not typical to move a registered file's location - instead you probably should unregister one DLL, and then register a second one, if you need to swap them out for debugging purposes.

Comment: @StayOnTarget Thanks for your reply. Since I been developed the "VB6 AddIn Proj" about 1 year ago, so I don't remember the detail when debugging of the project.
But it just work fine for me, besides some annoying bugs as above listed.
I just wondering if any better solution for the project. By the way, thanks for your reply.